# Why my api doesn't match the correct routes

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-routing

I have a weird situation... I have this api methods:

```
[Route("api/something")]
public class MyController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet("test-{id}")]
    public Task<T> method1() { ... }

    [HttpGet("test-something-{id}")]
    public Task<T> method2() { ... }
}
```

I want to call `api/something/test-something-1` but my api calls `api/something/test-1`

why?

Comment: Read [ask] and provide a [mcve]. There's too much wrong with this code. If you aren't behind a machine where you can verify the answers, don't post a question, but instead wait until you can.

Answer (score 2):

The route `"test-{id}"` matches `api/something/test-something-1` where template parameter would end up as `id = something-1`.

That is the reason why when you call `api/something/test-something-1` that it calls `method1` with route template `test-{id}`

When there are route conflicts like this then you should use route constraints to better differentiate routes.

```
[Route("api/something")]
public class MyController : Controller {
    [HttpGet("test-{id:int}")]//Matches GET api/something/test-1
    public Task<IActionResult> method1(int id) { 
        //...
    }

    [HttpGet("test-something-{id}")]//Matches GET api/something/test-something-any_id_here
    public Task<IActionResult> method2(string id) {
        //...
    }
}
```

You can apply route constraints to the second one as well if the `id` is suppose to be an `int` as well.

```
[HttpGet("test-something-{id:int}")]//Matches GET api/something/test-something-1
public Task<IActionResult> method2(int id) {
    //...
}
```

Reference: [Routing in ASP.NET Core : Route Constraint Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing#route-constraint-reference)

Answer (score -2):

Class declaration is incorrect

```
[RoutePrifix("api/something")]
public Class blabla : Controller
{
    [HttpGet("test-{id}")]
    public Task<T> method1{}

    [HttpGet("test-something-{id}")]
    public Task<T> method1{}
}
```

In route config file you have to enable attribute routing.

```
routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
```

Comment: class declaration is good, I was rushed when I wrote the class :D

Comment: Apart from the typos (`class` not `Class`, `RoutePrefix` not `RoutePrifix`), this does not answer the question.